# Remove security only for some requests wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-security, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to remove security for some specific requests in my api list using WSO2 API manager version 3.

For example, I have following requests

```
/customer - post
/products - get
/customer/address - get
```

In my case I don't need security for `/products - get`.

### Update

I tried the suggestion @Pubci getting request response

```
Invalid Credentials. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'Authorization : Basic ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'apikey: API_KEY
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each resource, you can enable/disable security.

1. Go to the resources tab.
2. Click on the relevant resource
3. Disable security.
4. Publish API

Please refer to the attached image.
[image]

For publishing api refer attached image

[image]

Comment: Worked ,I forgot to republish the API,updated the answer.Thank you.