# WSO2: endpoint is a rest service which has its own oauth2 service. Is it somehow possible to disable authentication in WSO2 for one API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

could you pls. advice me how to setup an API which has an endpoint already using oauth2 for authentication/authorization?

Is it possible to disable oauth2 in WSO2 for 1 endpoint only?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In WSO2 3.1.0 version, what you could do is before publishing the API, go to the resource section, from their select the resources, and disable the security from there. publish it again

This should solve your problem

Please see the link [Remove security only for some requests wso2 api manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118505/remove-security-only-for-some-requests-wso2-api-manager/61133046#61133046) in which the publisher has disabled the security for one of the APIs, you try disabling for all the APIs under that endpoint

Comment: In this answer is explained this with a snapshot where you can do it for WSO2 2.x and 3.x versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/64140174/11411150

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are accessing the API published on WSO2 API Manager, you must have the Wso2 API Bearer token to access that API. You cannot disable it for one endpoint.

Reference to invoke APIs :
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/learn/consume-api/invoke-apis/invoke-apis-using-tools/invoke-an-api-using-the-integrated-api-console/