# Expose unsecured url via WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API that I have setup in WSO2's API Manager Publisher tool.  All the calls work fine when called correctly with an Access Token.

But I have one url that I want anyone to be able to call.  (It is a customized Swagger UI page (different from the one built into the WSO2 tooling).)

To do this I add the Swagger UI url as a resource.  But when I go there it says:

> Required OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'

Generally, I really like this default.  (I want all my other API resources to require an Access Token.)  But for this one I don't have an access token and don't expect to.)

**Is it possible to publish one resource and not need any authentication?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also it can be done in 2.x versions of API Manager through disabling for each endpoint the security in publisher tool. In manage tab, resources section, for each resource/endpoint set the value x-auth-type to "None". Default value is "Application & Application User". This disable security and then authentication required for accesing to the selected API resources.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133046/3176125

Basically you can turn off for one of the resources while you allow security for the rest of the resources.